# How to select a computer on the network in a chooser panel in Java

Tags: java, networking

Is there a way to use something like a JFileChooser object to select a computer on the network, rather than a file or a directory?

I need to be able to pull up a chooser panel of some sort, browse to a list of servers on the network, and select the one I want to connect to.

Comment: Be more constructive, make a code readable

Comment: What else have you tried or researched so far (besides JFileChooser)?

Comment: @RomanC It seems to me that this question is quite constructive.

Comment: @Andremoniy you are not right, with the jfilechooser itself it cannot be done, so question is delete

Comment: @RomanC It seems to me, that author asks: **something LIKE a JFileChooser**. Hi doesn't ask how to use `JFileChooser` for such things, but some components for that.

Comment: @Andremoniy thus not a question really, coz we don't know what he meant

Comment: Unlikely. There's no platform-independent way to even figure out what computers exist on the network.

Comment: If this is networking then tag it to the corresponding tag, or ppl think like jfilechooser and swing

Comment: For clarification, I am using Windows, so cross-platform is not a big deal. Also, I realize that JFileChooser won't do what I want, but I need something SIMILAR to JFileChooser in functionality that allows me to browse for, and select, a computer on the network in the same way I would browse for, and select, a directory on my computer. I can't be the only person on the planet who has ever wanted to do this. Obviously, I could make a custom object to do this, but I was hoping someone had already done this before, or there was something already in the JDK. I am still fairly new to Java.

Comment: @StephenMacDougall Keep in mind that Java is inherently cross-platform, so functionality is not put in the standard library unless it can be done on most (if not all) supported platforms.

Comment: @duskwuff I realize that, but I just wanted to throw that out there in case someone had a Windows specific implementation of something. I didn't want to limit the answer to only cross-platform solutions, although cross-platform solutions are always preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide additional things for selectin in a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) if you pass a customited [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) to [its constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser%28javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView%29). I guess it should be possible to use [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) to implement a version which presents network hosts under a different [root](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getRoots%28%29) called “Network”, or something like this. You might be able to delegate many methods to the default file system view.

If you don't want to fake the file system itself, you'll have to either create your own dialog or find the correct hooks to modify an existing `JFileChooser` to custmize it to your needs, either by subclassing and overriding specific methods, or by navigating the component hierarchy and replacing certain components, or by a combination of these two. Sounds no less hackish than the faked file system view, so I'd go for that first, see if it works.

If you really only want to select computers, and won't navigate down the paths to actual files on these computers, then a file chooser is probably overkill, and a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) would probably be better suited. You can use it to display an [input dialog which shows a list of values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) to select from. Or if you want more control, you can create your own [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and pass that as the message argument for the [input dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks MvG! I suspected that I would have to go that route, but I was really hoping I was wrong. :-) I was hoping to avoid rolling my own chooser panel. I really do just want to present a list of computers on the network, and have the user select the computer he/she wants to connect to via a client app. It is primarily a sample app to exercise and demonstrate how to use an API, so there are limits to how much effort I am willing to put into creating a chooser panel.